# Resque worker not recognizing the Rails Mongoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, redis, resque

I am using resque in my application for delayed jobs, where i cant send emails & sms to bulk number of users asynchronously. And the data is stored in mongodb, mongoid is the ODM connects rails & mongo.

My mongoid model looks like this

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Geo::LocationHelper 

  field :name, :type => String
  field :desc, :type => String

  #resque queue name
  @queue = :item_notification

  #resque perform method
  def self.perform(item_id)
     @item = Item.find(item_id)

  end

end
```

I can able to add jobs to resque, i have verified using resque-web. Whenever i start an resque-worker

```
QUEUE=item_notification rake resque:work
```

i got the **uninitialized constant Item** , since i am using resque as rails gem and starting rake in rails root, i believe my mongoid models should be loaded.

After digging lot, i found that we can explicitly ask rake to load the environment by

```
  QUEUE=item_notification rake environment resque:work
```

but now also i got the same error **uninitialized constant Item**

can someone help me out?

and my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, its a problem in dev environment. after adding this line to into resque.rake task file

```
# load the Rails app all the time
namespace :resque do
  puts "Loading Rails environment for Resque"
  task :setup => :environment
  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:descendants).each { |klass|  klass.columns }
end
```

it works fine

The code taken from [GitHub-Resque-Wiki](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/wiki/FAQ)